# How to use Apache Sedona on Databricks Delta Live tables?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables

I am trying to run some geospatial transformations in Delta Live Table, using Apache Sedona. I tried defining a minimal example pipeline demonstrating the problem I encounter.

First cell of my Notebook, I install apache-sedona Python package:

```
%pip install apache-sedona
```

then I only use SedonaRegistrator.registerAll (to enable geospatial processing in SQL) and return an empty dataframe (that code is not reached anyway):

```py
import dlt
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from sedona.register import SedonaRegistrator
 
 
@dlt.table(comment="Test temporary table", temporary=True)
def my_temp_table():
    SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
    return spark.createDataFrame(data=[], schema=StructType([]))
```

I created the DLT Pipeline leaving everything as default, except for the spark configuration:

[image: DLT Spark Configuration]

Here is the uncut value of `spark.jars.packages`: `org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.2.0-incubating,org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.1.0-25.2`.

This is required according to this [documentation](https://sedona.apache.org/setup/install-python/).

When I run the Pipeline, I get the following error:

```
py4j.Py4JException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 2442, in _call_proxy
    return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/dlt/helpers.py", line 22, in call
    res = self.func()
  File "<command--1>", line 8, in my_temp_table
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-0ecd1771-412a-4887-9fc3-44233ebe4058/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sedona/register/geo_registrator.py", line 43, in registerAll
    cls.register(spark)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-0ecd1771-412a-4887-9fc3-44233ebe4058/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sedona/register/geo_registrator.py", line 48, in register
    return spark._jvm.SedonaSQLRegistrator.registerAll(spark._jsparkSession)
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I can reproduce this error by running spark on my computer and avoiding installing the packages specified in `spark.jars.packages` above.

I guess that this DLT Pipeline is not correctly configured to install Apache Sedona. I could not find any documentation describing how to install Sedona or other packages on a DLT Pipeline.

What I also tried so far, without success:

- using an init script -> not supported in DLT
- using a jar library -> not supported in DLT
- using a maven library -> not supported in DLT

Does anyone know how/if it is possible to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Unfortunately, installation of the 3rd party Java libraries it's not yet supported for the Delta Live Tables, so you can't use Sedona with DLT *right now*.</s>

Update on 1st August: init scripts in DLT are supported right now, so you can follow [Sedona instructions](https://sedona.apache.org/setup/databricks/?h=databricks#install-sedona-via-init-script-for-dbrs-73) for installing it via init scripts.  But be careful with selecting the right version, as DLT uses a modified runtime.

But if you're interested in the geospatial things on Databricks, you may look onto recently released [project Mosaic](https://github.com/databrickslabs/mosaic/) ([blog with announcement](https://databricks.com/blog/2022/05/02/high-scale-geospatial-processing-with-mosaic.html)) that supports many of the "standard" geospatial functions, but heavily optimized for Databricks, and also works with Delta Live Tables. Here is an example of DLT pipeline adopted from the [quickstart guide](https://databrickslabs.github.io/mosaic/usage/quickstart.html) that use functions like `st_contains`, etc.:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @AlexOtt ! I tried using Mosaic in a Databricks Notebook and with DLT and it works in both cases. It has the features I need for my project. However, I am missing an important piece: how to test my code using Mosaic in local? I cannot find a way to do that. I posted another question for this problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289894/how-to-run-mosaic-locally-outside-databricks

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  You can install jars on DLT clusters with a init script or by selecting the option to do a global library install.

Comment: @DonScott things are changing quickly in DLT world, few months ago init scripts didn't work...

Comment: The recommended mosaic library is no longer compatible with Delta Live Tables, which is very unfortunate. A Py4JError will occur, complaining about a public method not being whitelisted on class. I hope to see more activity on the Mosaic project as we have found it helpful.